# Salesforce CLI not available in sandbox

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, salesforcedx-cli

Under Connected Apps OAuth Usage, Salesforce CLI is not available to install. How to get it like below image
[image]

Comment: Are you having difficulty authenticating to this org with the Salesforce DX command-line tool? Why are you manipulating the Connected App directly?

Comment: This app is not available in my sandbox. I'm not able to connect visual studio with the sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VS Code, you can use the SFDX: Authorize An Org command, and it will allow you to specify production, sandbox, or a custom domain. You can also do this with the new [Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_unified.htm) command `sf`, such as:

```
sf auth web login -r https://test.salesforce.com -a some-alias -s
```

Which will log in to a sandbox, assign `some-alias` as the alias for parameters that reference an org (e.g. the org to operate on or a dev hub).

---

The Saleforce CLI as you have it listed there no longer exists, and has been superseded by the newer CLI, which will be listed as the Force CLI instead. The first time you authenticate successfully, it will automatically be available in this list. To authenticate to a Sandbox, make sure you use the -r parameter:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com -s
```

I'm not entirely sure that there's a GUI option for this, you should probably just run this command from a terminal instead (Ctrl-Shift-`).